# Django Post request for many to many field ValueError

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I am working on a post request in which the user chooses from a list of tags and makes combinations of tags. The combination of tags should then be posted. Nothing should get changed in the Tag table.

These are the models:

**models.py**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a human readable representation of the model instance."""
        return self.name or ''

    @property
    def tags(self):
        tags = self.tagging.values('tag')
        return tags.values('tag_id', 'tag__name', 'tag__language')


class Combination(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    gameround = models.ForeignKey(Gameround, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    tag_id = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.tag_id) or ''
```

This is the serializer for Combination.

**serializers.py**

```
class CombinationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  tag_id = TagWithIdSerializer(many=True, required=False, write_only=False)
  resource_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Resource.objects.all(),
                                                   required=True,
                                                   source='resource',
                                                   write_only=False)
  gameround_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Gameround.objects.all(),
                                                    required=False,
                                                    source='gameround',
                                                    write_only=False)
  user_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=CustomUser.objects.all(),
                                               required=False,
                                               source='user',
                                               write_only=False)

  class Meta:
    model = Combination
    depth = 1
    fields = ('id', 'user_id', 'gameround_id', 'resource_id', 'tag_id', 'created', 'score')

  def create(self, validated_data):
    user = None
    request = self.context.get("request")
    if request and hasattr(request, "user"):
      user = request.user

    score = 0

    tag_data = validated_data.pop('tag_id', None)

    combination = Combination(
      user=user,
      gameround=validated_data.get("gameround"),
      resource=validated_data.get("resource"),
      created=datetime.now(),
      score=score
    )
    combination.save()
    for tag_object in tag_data[0]:
      combination.tag_id.add(tag_object)
    return combination

  def to_representation(self, instance):
    rep = super().to_representation(instance)
    rep['tag_id'] = TagWithIdSerializer(instance.tag_id.all(), many=True).data
    return rep
```

I have tried posting the following JSON object to the database:

```
{
        "gameround_id": 2015685170,
        "resource_id": 327888,
        "tag_id": [{"id": 2014077506, "name": "corwn","language": "en"}]
}
```

I am getting a ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'name'.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Try to change `tag_id = TagWithIdSerializer` to `tag_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField`

Comment: I have and I am getting "tag_id": [
        "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received list."
    ]

Comment: Sorry the full change would be `tag_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Tag.objects.all(), many=True)`. Since you pass a list of ids, you will need `many=True`

Comment: I have and I am getting the same error message as before.

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide tag id for each tag not all tag data,

Try like this

```
{
            "gameround_id": 2015685170,
            "resource_id": 327888,
            "tag_id": [2014077506,2014077507]
    }
```

Comment: I have tried it again, it only leads to the following error: {"tag_id":[{"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."]},{"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."]}]}